# Marcar ponto critico na superficie - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Estou fazendo este script para marcar o ponto critico na superficie, só que ta dando erro : "Error in teste2 (line 26) plot(xs(1),xs(2),'r*')", alguem pode me ajudar?

```
clc
clear
H=[2 -2;-2 4];
f=[-4;0];
A=[2 1;1 -4];
b=[6; 0];
lb=zeros(2,1);
ub=[];
[xs,fval,flag] = quadprog(H,f,A,b,[], [], lb, ub, [])

fprintf('%s ', 'Convergente: ')
if flag >0
fprintf('%s \n', 'OK')
disp('Solução obtida:')
xs;
else
fprintf('%s \', 'Não convergente!')
end

x = [0:0.01:5];
y = [0:0.01:5];
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = -4.*X + X.^2 - 2.*X.*Y + 2.*Y.^2;      %função objetivo
meshc(X,Y,Z)
hold on
plot(xs(1),xs(2),'r*')
hold on
```

Comment: Não tem `xs` declarado em nenhum lugar do programa.

Comment: onde e como deveria declarar ?

Comment: O `xs` está declarado da maneira certa, pois ele é a saida da funcão `quadprog` sem stress!

Comment: @ViniciusSouza Este script funcionou ok pra mim. Só recomendo usar 
`plot3(xs(1),xs(2),-4.*xs(1) + xs(1).^2 - 2.*xs(1).*xs(2) + 2.*xs(2).^2,'g*')` para colocar ao ponto na coordenada `z` certa.
Se você tiver mais alguma coisa no debug faz uns comentários ou edite a pergunta eu ou alguém pode ter mais sorte.

Comment: @Guto deu certo agora, obrigado